# PHP : Change Cookie Value

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, geolocation

I use Geo Plugin for get user state/ County and store it in cookie. So website's data will display data from that state/ County. But issue is what if User Change State/ County then site will reload and again that included config file will call and set cookie to current state/ County from that Geo Plugin.

**Here is my cookie code**

```
// get user location
require_once(LIBRARY_DIR.'/geoplugin.class.php');

$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
setcookie("county", $geoplugin->region);
```

Now user change county from dropdown list then again it set to current county. what I do for prevent again to select default/ Current county from Geo Plugin ?

Answer (score -1):

Only set the cookie if it is not already set.

```
if( !isset( $_COOKIE['country'] ) )
     setcookie( 'country' , $geoplugin->region );
```